# taking input into vector using for-range loop

Tags: c++, vector, input

First of all, I want my user to tell me how many numbers he have to input? Which will create that number of elements in vector initialized to zero. Then I want to use
for-range loop to insert the elements into the vector and similarly an other for-range loop to display the vector elements.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::cin;

int main(){
  int c;
  cin>>c;
  vector<int> ivec(c); 
  
  for(int i : ivec){ //for taking input and adding it into vector 
    cin>>i;
    ivec.push_back(i);
  }

  for(int i: ivec){ //displaying the vector 
    cout<<i<< "\t";
    }
 

  return 0;
}
```

but my output is very different from my expectation.

My actual output is coming as:-

Output :-

```
3
4
5
6
0 0 0 4 5 6
```

can somebody explain me please? And can I actually use a for-range loop for inserting vector elements?

Comment: Is the output you show the *actual* or *expected* output? If it's the actual output, then what's the expected output? And what is the input that causes the unexpected output?

Comment: And have you tried to *debug* your program? Like for example stepping through the code, statement by statement, in a debugger while you monitor variables and their values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` have 2 sizes.
One is actual-used size and the other is reserved-size.

Below creates a vector with *actual-size* `n`.

```
std::vector<int> v(size_type n)
```

While this creates a vector with empty size and reserved size `n`.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(n);
```

`std::vector<T>::push_back()` increases the *actual-size* by 1 at the end.
So your code is

1. Create a vector with *actual-size* `c`.
2. Add element at the back.

---

So you should replace your code to

```
std::vector<int> vec(c);
for(auto& i : ivec){
  cin>>i;
}
```

This creates a `vector` with size `c` and modifies its element.

Or

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int i=0; i<c; ++i) {
  int temp;
  std::cin >> temp;
  vec.push_back(temp);
}
```

where this creates an empty `vector` and pushes the element at the end.

See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for more info.

Comment: Yes it's working thank you, But can you explain me why I need to use reference here? and why my code isn't working. I didn't get what you said ? I know it will create vector of size c already then how ivec.push_back(i) is pushing after that vector?

Comment: @Shubharthak `std::vector` has 2 sizes. One is the actual used size, and the other is the capacity size which is pre-allocated memory size. I think you're confusing both.
I'll add more description in my answer.